# Find and solve the following recurrence relation using generating functions.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $a_n$ denote the number of ways to partition $\{1, 2, 3, . . . , n\}$ into two disjoint subsets. In this case a partition of a set is two non empty sets where the partition (1,2)=(2,1) ie if n =2 there is only one way to partition this set.

The solution to the reccurence relation should be the number of ways to select a non-empty subset of $n-1$ or $2^{n-1} -1$ the -1 is to remove the empty set.

My question is Find a recurrence relation for $a_n$ s.t $ n ≥ 2$ then solvve it using generating functions. My attempt is as follows:

$a_2=1$ $a_3=3$ $a_4=7$ by calculating directly.

$a_k=2(a_{k-1})+1$ where $k\geq1$

new $a_0=1$ $a_1=3$ $a_2=7$

$\sum_{k=1} a_k x^k=2 \sum_{k=1}a_{k-1}x^k+\sum_{k=1}x^k$

$g(x)=\sum_{k=0} a_k x^k$

$\sum_{k=1} a_k x^k=2 x\sum_{k=1}a_{k-1}x^{k-1}+x\sum_{k=1}x^{k-1}$

$g(x)-a_0 =2xg(x)+xg(x)$

$g(x)(1-2x) =a_0+xg(x)$

$g(x)(1-2x) =a_0+x(1+x+x^2+....)=a_0+x+x^2+x^3+...$since $a_0=1$

$1+x+x^2+x^3+...=\frac{1}{1-x}$

$g(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-2x)}=\frac{2}{1-2x}-\frac{1}{1-2x}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-2x} -\frac{1}{1-2x}= \frac{1}{2}(2x)^n -(1)^n = 2^{n-1}-1$ and by sheer asshattery we have our solution. generating functions are the #1 worst way to solve this.

Comment: Must the subsets be nonempty?  For $n=2$ would it not be two ways?  $(\{1,2\},\emptyset)$ and $(\{1\},\{2\})$?  Moving from $n$ to $n+1$, taking a partition of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ of the form $(A,B)$ create a partition of $\{1,2,\dots,n+1\}$ by appending $\{n+1\}$ to one of them, i.e. $(A\cup \{n+1\},B)$ and $(A,B\cup \{n+1\})$.  This would give the recurrence $a_n=2a_{n-1}$.

Comment: in our def'n of a partition both subsets that make up the partition must be non-empty and order doesnt matter. so the only partition for n=2 is $(\{1\} \{2 \} )$ so for n=1 there is no way to partition that set.

Comment: If you insist the subsets must be non-empty, then instead you can build the partitions of $\{1,2,\dots,n+1\}$ from the old as again $(A\cup \{n+1\},B),(A,B\cup \{n+1\}),(\{1,2,\dots,n\},\{n+1\})$ giving recurrence $a_n=2a_{n-1}+1$ as you wrote.  Solving for closed form, looking at the homogeneous piece you have it is of the form $c\cdot 2^n$, and the non-homogeneous piece is a constant, so it is of the form $a_n=c\cdot 2^n + d$.  Solving for $d$ gives $d=-1$.  Then using initial conditions gives $c=\frac{1}{2}$, giving as expected $a_n=2^{n-1}-1$

Comment: yeah sadly im not allowed to use any method but generating functions for my assignment. ironically i have managed to get the solution in two different ways but every time i try generating functions it breacks

Comment: I actually found it ! thanks for your help.